# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource - when trying to send email via node.js

Tags: jquery, node.js, reactjs, cors

When I try to send an email using nodejs and node mailer, sometimes it sends the email, but sometimes it throws the following error below:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://nodejsmailer' from origin 'https://org' has been blocked 
by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

This is my jQuery code:

```
function SendEmail() {  
        $.ajax({  
           contentType: 'application/json',
           url: "https://nodejsmailer",
           type: "POST",
             body: JSON.stringify({
                  'to': to,
                  'body': body,
                  'subject': subject
            }),
           headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
                "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
            },
            success: function(data) {  
                console.log(data);
            },  
            eror: function(data) {  
                console.log(data);
            }
            })
    }
```

This is my node js code:

```
const express = require('express');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var qs = require('qs');
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express()
app.use(cors());
const port = 5000;
app.use(express.json());
    app.post('/sendemail', (req, res) => {
        var options = {
            from: 'noreply@somewhere.com',
            to: req.body['to'],
            subject: req.body['subject'],
            text: req.body['body']
        };
        res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        transporter.sendMail(options, function(error, info) {
            if (error) {
                res.end(error);
            } else {
                res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
                res.end('Email sent.\n');
            }
        });
    });
```

What could be causing this issue? Could it be because I am behind a proxy?

Comment: As asma already pointed out in their answer, you need to add `app.use(cors());` to make your api use this middleware.

Comment: it is there, but it does not help.

Answer (score 0):

Following solution might help you :

**App.js**

```
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Comment: express.json, bodyparser.json() and epxress.urlendcoded(), do nothing to solve this problem